# как подключать изображения на wordpress

Tags: wordpress

у меня есть сайт на wordpress и чтбы подключить картинки я просто к атрибуту src добавляю в начале

```
<?php get_template_director_uri() ?>
```

Все как бы отлично работает, но мне кажется, что это костыль и существует более простой способ
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В целом уже хорошо, но лучше загружать изображения в библиотеку и выводить через `wp_get_attachment_image` или `wp_get_attachment_image_url`. Но это имеет смысл если вы даете пользователю возможность изменять изображения через админку.

Также, все функции для вывода картинок имеют общие хуки, которые могут использовать разные плагины. К примеру если на сайте все картинки выводятся через стандартные WordPress функции, то можно 1-м хуком изменить атрибут src на data-src и подключить lazy load.

Подробнее: https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_attachment_image или https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_get_attachment_image_url

Comment: а нельзя добавить какой нибудь фильтр, чтобы wordpress сам подставлял ко всем картинкам данный префикс?

Comment: Весь вывод картинок в вп сводится к функциям wp_get_attachement_image. Если вы будете придерживаться этого формата в своей теме, то можно использовать любые фильтры внутри этой функции. Если хотите изменить аттрибуты можно юзать этот фильтр: wp_get_attachment_image_attributes